# Reverse printing from txt file using recursion in C

Tags: c, file, recursion, fseek, ftell

I need to write out .txt file backwards in terminal using recursion, but it seems I'm stuck.
This is my code so far, but it creates an infinite loop. Also, the procedure *write()* should have only 1 parameter - pointer to file.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void write(FILE **f)
{
    char cur;

    fseek(*f,-1,SEEK_CUR);
    cur = fgetc(*f);

    printf("%c",cur);
    write(f);
}

int main(void)
{
    FILE *f;
    f = fopen("text.txt","r");
    fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);
    write(&f);
    
    fclose(f);
    return 0;
}
```

I wanted to use *fseek* and *ftell* functions, they seem to be best way to do this.
My expected output would be:
**FILE**
`Hello world`
**OUTPUT**
`dlrow olleH`

Comment: Considering they have a infinite call stack, they won't even be able to see the print outputs.

Comment: @Cassie can you please provide the outputs in the file, if any?

Comment: Your recursive function has no termination criteria. It always makes the recursive call, so it goes on forever until stack overflow. You need logic in a recursive function that decides whether to make the recursive call or not.

Comment: @RohanAsokan Right now my output is *dddddddddddddd* until I stop the program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you have given, the way to do the problem recursively using `fseek` and `ftell` can be written as follows,

```
#include <stdio.h>

void write(FILE **f)
{
    char cur;
    cur = fgetc(*f);
    printf("%c", cur);
    if (ftell(*f) == 1) return;
    fseek(*f,-2,SEEK_CUR);
    write(f);
}

int main(void)
{
    FILE *f;
    f = fopen("text.txt","r");
    fseek(f, -1, SEEK_END);
    write(&f);
    
    fclose(f);
    return 0;
}
```

Considering the file is read in reverse, the stop condition requires a bit of thinking. The position of a pointer is returned by `ftell` and using this we can detect if the current position of the pointer is at the start of the file or not (as in if it is equal to 1).

There were tiny mistakes in your code - the recursion never stopped (as pointed out in the comments), make sure you always have a stop inside your recursive functions.

The order of your `fseek` needs changing so that you read the first character in properly.

And you need to use a -2 inside your `fseek` to move to the previous character. This is because of the fact that `fgetc` will advance the pointer by 1 and you will have to go back by 1 character to reach the character that was read just now and you then you want to move it backwards by one more, so that you get to the character before the one that was just read. Thanks to [p-j-supports-women-in-poland](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6110094/p-j-supports-women-in-poland) for pointing this out.

Otherwise the above code will make it clear for you, I hope. if you still got doubts ping me in the comments. Happy to help :)

Comment: what is the `fseek` for? It shows lack of understanding how the recursion works.

Comment: Sorry what? Can you be more clear? Thanks

Comment: It is not needed at all.  Type for cur is wrong. Vary bad code. No double `*` pointers needed.

Comment: Umm..it is as the fgetc increments the pointer by 1 and you want to move it two positions back to read the previous character - if that makes sense to you. And yes I agree with the wrong type for cur. I am sorry. But you do not have to be so rude.

Comment: @RohanAsokan Thank you! Code works for me and does exactly what I need.

Comment: Glad that it worked. Please mark it as the answer. Would help others moving through SO.

Answer (score 0):

This task is actually not very suitable for the recursion but ..

EDIT I actually misunderstood your question but it is same trivial.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void writeRecursive(FILE *file)
{
    int ch;
    if(fread(&ch, 1, 1, file) == 1) 
    { 
        writeRecursive(file);
        fwrite(&ch, 1, 1, file);
    }
    else
    {
        rewind(file);
    }

}

int main(void)
{
    FILE *fi = fopen("a.txt", "w+");
    char c;

    fprintf(fi, "123456789");
    rewind(fi);

    writeRecursive(fi);
    rewind(fi);
    while(fread(&c, 1, 1, fi) == 1)
    {
        printf("%c", c);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/edGfKa

or

```
void writeRecursive(FILE *file)
{
    int ch;
    if((ch = fgetc(file)) != EOF) 
    { 
        writeRecursive(file);
        fputc(ch, file);
    }
    else
    {
        rewind(file);
    }

}
```

---

Old answer

```
void printRecursive(FILE *fi, FILE *fo)
{
    char ch;
    if(fread(&ch, 1, 1, fi) == 1) 
    { 
        printRecursive(fi,fo);
        fwrite(&ch, 1, 1, fo);
    }

}

int main(void)
{
    FILE *fi = stdin, *fo = stdout;

    printRecursive(fi, fo);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/YjfvcP

Comment: The question is clearly to reverse the file and write it to the same file. And hence the recursion.

Comment: @RohanAsokan The question is literally "I need to print .txt file backwards using recursion".  Nowhere is "write it to the same file" even implied.

Comment: @RohanAsokan I just need to wrtite it out in terminal, not in file

Comment: @Cassie Cool. I have made some progress, it now prints the content. Just figuring wth is the end clause, hehe.

Comment: @Cassie here you have a recursive function which reverses the file

Comment: From certain size of the input file the code won't work any more, because the program would have run out of stack space.